# jQuery - increase and decrease value of input by button

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var x = 1;
$("#sinolo input").attr('value', x);
$("#inc").click(function(){
  $("#sinolo input").attr('value', x++);
});
$("#dec").click(function(){
  $("#sinolo input").attr('value', x--);
});
```

```css
#sinolo{
 width: 35%;
 float: left;
}
#sinolo input{
 width: 45%;
 border: none;
 text-align: center;
}
#sinolo button{
 width: 25%;
 font-size: 10px;
 padding: 8px 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="sinolo">
  <button id="dec" class="btn btn-info fa fa-minus pull-left"></button>
  <input type="text" name="" value="">
  <button id="inc" class="btn btn-info fa fa-plus pull-right"></button>
</div>
```

I face two problems as you can see.

1. At start when I press the button the process is delaying and begins the counting by second click.
2. If I press the + (plus) button and then the - (minus) button, the process is not working properly.
   What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `++` (the [increment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_())) behaves differently depending on whether it is before or after the variable in question (the [`--` decrement operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Decrement_(--)) is the same). Placed after the variable, like you have, it means "give me the value of the variable, then increase it by one". Placed before the variable (e.g. `++x`), it means "increase the value of the variable, then give me the new value".

Because you are doing `x++` or `x--`, you are getting the value of the variable **before** the operation. Use `++x` and `--x` and your code will work fine.

```js
var x = 1;
 $("#sinolo input").attr('value', x);
     $("#inc").click(function(){
       $("#sinolo input").attr('value', ++x);
     });
     $("#dec").click(function(){
       $("#sinolo input").attr('value', --x);
     });
```

```css
#sinolo{
 width: 35%;
 float: left;
}
#sinolo input{
 width: 45%;
 border: none;
 text-align: center;
}
#sinolo button{
 width: 25%;
 font-size: 10px;
 padding: 8px 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="sinolo">
  <button id="dec" class="btn btn-info fa fa-minus pull-left"></button>
  <input type="text" name="" value="">
  <button id="inc" class="btn btn-info fa fa-plus pull-right"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You've just to use *pre-increment* (`--x` and `++x`) instead of *post-increment* (`x--` and `x++`) since :

- **Post-increment (`x++`):** Increments the value of variable `x` after processing the current statement.
- **Pre-increment (`++x`):** Increments the value of variable `x` before processing the current statement.

Hope this helps.

```js
var x = 1;
$("#sinolo input").attr('value', x);
$("#inc").click(function(){
  $("#sinolo input").attr('value', ++x);
});
$("#dec").click(function(){
  $("#sinolo input").attr('value', --x);
});
```

```css
#sinolo{
 width: 35%;
 float: left;
}
#sinolo input{
 width: 45%;
 border: none;
 text-align: center;
}
#sinolo button{
 width: 25%;
 font-size: 10px;
 padding: 8px 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="sinolo">
  <button id="dec" class="btn btn-info fa fa-minus pull-left"></button>
  <input type="text" name="" value="">
  <button id="inc" class="btn btn-info fa fa-plus pull-right"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Remeber how the -- and ++ operator work, if you put them after you're updating after the fact, so you modify the value of `x` after changing the input value, so just put them before

```
var x = 1;
$("#sinolo input").attr('value', x);
    $("#inc").click(function(){
      $("#sinolo input").attr('value', ++x);
    });
    $("#dec").click(function(){
      $("#sinolo input").attr('value', --x);
    });
```